# QThread.finished signal isn't emitted after worker finishes

Tags: python, pyqt, signals-slots, qthread

I have the following code:

```py
import time

from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QObject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication


class Worker(QObject):

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Worker is finished")


class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.show()

        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.on_thread_finished)
        self.thread.start()

    def on_thread_finished(self):
        print("Thread finished")
        self.thread.deleteLater()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

Run it, it shows the window, prints `Worker is finished`, nothing more. That's weird. IMHO when the worker is finished, the thread should be finished too, which means the `on_thread_finished` method should be called and `Thread finished` should be printed. But it wasn't. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when the worker is finished, the thread should be finished too

That's not how it works.  Your `Worker::run` method is being invoked as a `slot` via the usual `signal`/`slot` mechanism after which the `QThread` will continue to process events as normal.

If you want to terminate the `QThread` when `Worker::run` has completed you need to tell it to do so explicitly...

```
import time

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QThread, QObject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication


class Worker(QObject):

    # Constructor accepts the QThread as a parameter and stashes it
    # for later use.
    def __init__(self, thread):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.m_thread = thread
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Worker is finished")

        # We're done so ask the `QThread` to terminate.
        if self.m_thread:
            self.m_thread.quit()


class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.show()

        self.thread = QThread()

        # Pass the QThread to the Worker's ctor.
        self.worker = Worker(self.thread)
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.on_thread_finished)
        self.thread.start()

    def on_thread_finished(self):
        print("Thread finished")
        self.thread.deleteLater()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

Very 'inelegant' but it conveys the idea.

A simpler alternative that springs to mind would be to simply make use of `QThread::currentThread()`, in which case your `Worker::run` method becomes...

```
class Worker(QObject):
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Worker is finished")

        # We're done so ask the `QThread` to terminate.
        QThread.currentThread().quit()
```

Comment: QThread.currentThread().quit()  gives me Fatal Python error: Aborted

Comment: that is QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running
Aborted (core dumped) outside my IDE

Comment: @pippo1980 The code shown works for me.  If you're having some specific problem then please open a new question.

Comment: my example uses a loop in the worker , so sometimes I am just stopping the thread and close the main window, but if I dont quit the thread and close main window I get the error, it works better to me emitting finish signal from the worker  to main

Comment: cant edit your answer queque is full, think for novice like me would be nice to point out that  QThread.currentThread() Returns a pointer to a QThread which manages the currently executing thread.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `moveToThread` instead of reimplementing [QThread.run](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#run), the thread will start its own event-loop which will wait until `exit/quit` is explicitly called. The `finished` signal is only emitted after the event-loop has stopped (and/or once `run` returns). The usual way to handle this scenario is to emit a custom signal from the worker, and connect it to the thread's `quit` slot. (NB: cross-thread signal-slot connections are guaranteed to be thread-safe).

So your example will work as expected with the following changes:

```
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Worker is finished")
        self.finished.emit()


class MainWindow(QWidget):    
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
```