# PyqtSignal is not terminating the Thread after self.finished.emit() Signal in PyQt5

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, qthread

I am trying to build a POS app that communicates with an API with PyQT5. I have a simple POS app GUI in Main Thread and when Pay button is pressed a new Thread is created that takes the total amount entry value and send it to the API in order to execute the payment process.

This is the code for the main Window UI:

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # The design
        self.setupUI()
        # Line Edit Focused has the last widget focused before the button is pressed
        self.lineEditFocused = None
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.app.focusChanged.connect(self.on_focusChanged)
        self.wait_after_completion = 5.0
        # Pay Thread

        self.credentials = tokens

        # (self.credentials.json())

    def setupUI(self):
       ...(setupUI code to create the POS UI)...

        self.Entry_button_PayPod.clicked.connect(self.POS_accept_request)
        self.show()

    def POS_accept_request(self):
        self.pay_thread_1 = QThread()

        self.worker_1 = Worker(thread=self.pay_thread_1, total_amount_value=self.input_text_total_amount.text(),
                               token=self.credentials.json())

        self.worker_1.moveToThread(self.pay_thread_1)

        self.pay_thread_1.started.connect(
            self.worker_1.run)

        self.worker_1.finished.connect(self.pay_thread_1.quit)
        self.worker_1.finished.connect(self.worker_1.deleteLater)
        self.pay_thread_1.finished.connect(self.pay_thread_1.deleteLater)

        self.pay_thread_1.finished.connect(self.killthread)
        self.pay_thread_1.finished.connect(self.end_fun)

        self.pay_thread_1.start()

    def killthread(self):
        for th in threading.enumerate():
            print(th,'',th.is_alive())
        print('IN:', threading.enumerate())

    def end_fun(self):
        print('End fun')
        print(threading.enumerate())
```

This is the class Worker code:

```
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, thread, total_amount_value='', token='', port=44333):
        super().__init__()
        self.total_amount_value = total_amount_value
        self.token = token
        self.port = port
        self.m_thread = thread

    def run(self):  # , value, answer, port=44333

        def amount_to_MDU(amount_to_transform):

            if amount_to_transform == '':
                return 0.0
            else:
                amount_to_transform = float(amount_to_transform)
                return amount_to_transform * 100

        async def get_HTTP_status(IP_address_CS, port, headers, flag=True):
            '''
            :param IP_address_CS: IP address of API
            :param port: default port of API is 44333
            :param headers: headers for status method
            :param flag: flag is default True in order to run while loop
            :return:
            '''
            answer = ''
            while flag:
                async with httpx.AsyncClient(verify=False) as client:
                    tasks = client.get('https://' + IP_address_CS + ':' + str(port) + '/status', headers=headers)
                    reqs = await asyncio.gather(tasks)
                    try:
                        answer = reqs[0].json()['events'][0]['event']
                    except:
                        answer = 'Waiting1'

                if answer in ['Waiting', 'Waiting1', 'Payment', 'NewPayment', 'PayInStarted', 'CancelPayment',
                              'StoppingPayment', 'Refund', 'PayInComplete', 'Change', 'Idle']:
                    continue
                elif answer in ['NotEnoughFloat', 'BillDeviceDisconnected', 'CoinDeviceDisconnected', 'PayoutJammed',
                                'PayoutOutOfService', 'SoftwareError', 'NotePathOpen', 'BillJammed', 'CashboxRemoved',
                                'CalibrationFailedPaid', 'CoinMechError', 'MaintainenceRequired', 'RCCassetteRemoved',
                                'Full']:
                    flag = False
                else:
                    flag = False

            return answer

        value = amount_to_MDU(self.total_amount_value)
        IP_address = CashGenic_IP_address
        flag_close = True
        if value == 0.0:
            print('No value inserted')
        elif value > 0:
            # IP address with port
            complete_IP = 'https://' + IP_address + ':' + str(self.port) + '/session'

            # Parameters of PayAmount API method
            parameters = {
                "request": "PayAmount",
                "value": value
            }

            # Headers of PayAmount API method
            headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                       'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.token['access_token']}  # answer token

            # Session PayAmount API method
            HTTP_PayAmount_answer = httpx.post(url=complete_IP, json=parameters, headers=headers, verify=False)

            # If payment is successful then 
            if HTTP_PayAmount_answer.status_code == 200 and HTTP_PayAmount_answer.json()['responseCode'] == 0:
                
                # Get the status in loop
                event = asyncio.run(get_HTTP_status(IP_address, self.port, headers))
            
                print('This is the last event of PayAmount:' + str(event))
                if event in ['PaymentComplete', 'RefundComplete', 'CancelComplete',
                             'StopComplete']:  # Check for event Idle
                    while flag_close:
                        # PaymentComplete event is for completion of Payment
                        # RefundComplete event is for completion of Payment after Refund
                        # CancelComplete event is for completion of Cancel of Payment
                        # Stop Complete event is for completion of Stop of Payment
                        CLOSE_ANSWER = httpx.post(url=complete_IP,
                                                  # There is a chance that Here CloseSession won't work?
                                                  json={"request": "CloseSession"},
                                                  headers=headers,
                                                  verify=False)
                        try:
                            if CLOSE_ANSWER.json()['responseCode'] == 0:
                                flag_close = False
                        except:
                            continue

                    # # Kill Thread
                    # self.finished.emit()

                #PayOutError occurs when there is change available so we should cancel the request
                elif event in ['PayOutError', 'NotEnoughFloat', 'BillDeviceDisconnected', 'CoinDeviceDisconnected',
                               'PayoutJammed',
                               'PayoutOutOfService', 'SoftwareError', 'NotePathOpen', 'BillJammed', 'CashboxRemoved',
                               'CalibrationFailedPaid', 'CoinMechError', 'MaintainenceRequired', 'RCCassetteRemoved',
                               'Full']:
                    # Cancel the Payment
                    HTTP_Cancel_answer = httpx.post(url=complete_IP,
                                                    json={'request': 'CancelPayment'},
                                                    headers=headers, verify=False)
                    print('After PayOutError:', HTTP_Cancel_answer.json())

                    if HTTP_Cancel_answer.status_code == 200 and HTTP_Cancel_answer.json()['responseCode'] == 0:
                        event = asyncio.run(get_HTTP_status(IP_address, self.port, headers))
                        print('Last event of Cancel of PayOutError', event)
                        if event == 'RefundComplete':
                            while flag_close:
                                CLOSE_ANSWER = httpx.post(url=complete_IP,
                                                          # There is a chance that Here CloseSession won't work?
                                                          json={"request": "CloseSession"},
                                                          headers=headers,
                                                          verify=False)
                                try:
                                    print(CLOSE_ANSWER.json())
                                    if CLOSE_ANSWER.json()['responseCode'] == 0:
                                        flag_close = False
                                except:
                                    continue
                            # # Kill Thread
                            # self.finished.emit()
                else:
                    print('Error 404. Something went wrong at Payment')  # Edw tha mpei pop message
        elif value < 0:

            # IP address with port
            complete_IP = 'https://' + IP_address + ':' + str(self.port) + '/session'

            # Parameters of RefundAmount API method
            parameters = {
                "request": "RefundAmount",
                "value": abs(value)
            }

            # Headers of RefundAmount API method
            headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                       'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.token['access_token']}  # answer token

            # Session RefundAmount API method
            HTTP_RefundAmount_answer = httpx.post(url=complete_IP, json=parameters, headers=headers, verify=False)
            print(HTTP_RefundAmount_answer.json())  # Here I can take the GUID

            if HTTP_RefundAmount_answer.status_code == 200 and HTTP_RefundAmount_answer.json()[
                'responseCode'] == 0:  # If token can ensure Refund
                event = asyncio.run(get_HTTP_status(IP_address, self.port, headers))
                print('This is the last event of RefundAmount:' + str(event))
                # if event == 'PaymentComplete' or event == 'RefundComplete':
                while flag_close:
                    CLOSE_ANSWER = httpx.post(url=complete_IP,
                                              # There is a chance that Here CloseSession won't work?
                                              json={"request": "CloseSession"},
                                              headers=headers,
                                              verify=False)
                    try:
                        print(CLOSE_ANSWER.json())
                        if CLOSE_ANSWER.json()['responseCode'] == 0:
                            flag_close = False
                    except:
                        print("Exception")
                        continue
                # # Kill Thread
                # self.finished.emit()
            elif HTTP_RefundAmount_answer.status_code == 200 and HTTP_RefundAmount_answer.json()['responseCode'] == 12:
                pass
            else:
                print('Something went wrong with Dispense')
        else:
            print('Value Error')

        self.finished.emit()
```

So when Pay Button is pressed then the **POS_accept_request** function of Window class is called which create a QThread object and a Worker object. Then I move the Worker Object at the the Thread one and when the Thread start it runs the **run** function of Worker class which has the whole procedure of the API payment. My code is running fine, but with a huge disadvantage. When I used the [threading.enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.enumerate) method(end_fun function of main Window class) of [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) library to see the active threads. I saw that the Threads that I created are not being deleted, despite using self.finished.emit() at the end of **run** function to signal the end of the Thread. Which means that everytime a user tries to make a payment, a new thread is created without deleting the previous one and this eventually will crash the app. I tried to follow this [tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread/) in order to use Threads in PyQt5. My question is there any other solution to terminate the Thread when the **run** method of Worker class ends its execution, I excepted when the self.finished.emit() method to signal the termination of the Thread?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72216161/qthread-finished-signal-isnt-emitted-after-worker-finishes  QThread.finished signal isn't emitted after worker finishes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72772096/pyqt-qthread-requestinterrupt-not-changing-isinterruptrequested PyQt Qthread requestInterrupt() not changing isInterruptRequested()